# Vaadin: Collapse all Tabs in an Accordion

Tags: vaadin

I'm wondering if there's a way to collapse all tabs on an accordion. Found no such method in [TabSheets](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TabSheet.html) either. I would like to basically display the tab names and show the content when I select the tab. By default the first tab is always opened.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaadin 23 has method:

```
Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
...add component
accordion.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, I found no way either.  You can workaround this by adding an "empty" Tab.  Combined with some styling, that worked quite well.  E.g.:

```
@Grapes([
@Grab('org.vaadin.spring:spring-boot-vaadin:0.0.3'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-server:7.4.0.beta1'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:7.4.0.beta1'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:7.4.0.beta1'),
])
import org.vaadin.spring.VaadinUI
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest
import com.vaadin.ui.*

@com.vaadin.annotations.Theme('valo')
@VaadinUI
class MyUI extends UI {
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new Accordion().with{ c->
            ['A','B','C'].each{ c.addTab(new Label("Some $it"), it) }
            c.addTab(new CssLayout(), "[x] close all") // XXX
            return c
        })
    }
}
```